# error occured during data refresh in Power Bi Report Server

Tags: powerbi

While installing a scheduled dashboard update on Power Bi Report Server, I get an error: 1056505856: COM error: Microsoft.BIServer.HostingEnvironment, ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException. I looked through a bunch of forums and descriptions of those support, but I did not find a solution to the problem. At the same time, when I check the connection to the database, my connection is established. Has anyone received such an error?

I turned to the forums and in those support. Also wrote to the GPT chat. All options (to check the correctness of the connection, connection) have already been completed. Everything works, there are accesses. The versions are the same both on Desktop and on the server. Please help me solve this error.